# Redux-Persist not working with SSR .getInitialProps() function from NextJs?

Tags: redux, state, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-persist

I tried to implement redux-persist for my SSR NextJs application without any success. I pretty much use the same code from the basic usage example https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#basic-usage

As some guys of you may know the .getInitialProps() (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) function from NextJs fetches data serverside. So Redux-Persist for me only works, when I fetch the data clientside after persist/PERSIST & persist/REHYDRATE was called already.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong or did not understand the concept fully, but here is my procedure & how actions are being called from the reducer:

1. `{type: '@@redux/INITr.6.5.z.4.q'}`
2. `{type: 'myDataFetchingReducer', payload: xxxxx }` -> data is fetched successfully via getInitialProps(), the redux state & store is being updated with the new data
3. `{type: '@@redux/INITr.6.5.z.4.q'}` -> state & store still looks good
4. `{type: 'persist/PERSIST'}` -> state & store still looks godd
5. `{type: 'persist/HYDRATE'}` -> state & store get's reset to the state,
   before myDataFetchingReducer was called

Would be cool to get some insights at this point. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here or if my understanding of how it should work is wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: Hey! After hours of debugging I found a fix which worked for me, but redux-persist is very buggy especially with NextJs/SSR there are so many edge cases & bugs. I don't know why so many people use such a outdated library, but It's still better then write a persist solution from scratch i guess.


I fixed it temporarily by having client/server separation (https://www.robinwieruch.de/redux-persist-next-js) & ignoring the <PersistGate> for some pages (for example login/redirect)